# How do go assembly achieve macro function calls between different assembly files?

Tags: go, assembly, macros

I don't know how to achieve macro function calls between different assembly files with go assembly.
Once I try to do this using #include "XX.s", the error of a symbol duplicated defined always ocurred.

I expect to achieve macro function calls between different assembly files with go assembly.
Suppose file A has a macro function A1, file B has a macro function B1,
I want B can call A1 without the need to merge the two file into one file.

Comment: Show your code please.  I recommend putting shared macros into a common source file (mark it as `//go:build ignore`) to include.  That source file must not define any functions or variables, only macros.

Comment: the assembly language supported by your tool should have some form of include operand, did you read the documentation?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. The problem has been solved. The cause of the problem is that the last macro in the file did not add a new line or the last function didn't add a new line between the function body and RET.